# How to concatenate a string with blankspaces?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to create a 10-character string. If the string has less than 10 characters i need to append blank spaces till complete the entire 10-character string. I do the following but I have no succes, the result string has only one blank space concateneted in the end:

```
public void MyMethod(string[] mystrings)
{

    mystring[i].PadRight(10- mystrings[i].length)
    // Here I need a 10 char string. For example:
    // "1234567   "

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `myString.PadRight(10)`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a.aspx

Comment: Since the string is inside an array of strings I cannot use `PadRight()`directly to mystring[i]. I must use the returned value and reasing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`String.PadRight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright.aspx):

```
mystring = mystring.PadRight(10, ' ');
```

(You can omit the second parameter, as in your case, when you use spaces).

Note however, that if `mystring` is already longer than 10 characters, it will remain longer. It is not clear from your question, if you need a string with *exactly* 10 characters length. If so, then do something like:

```
mystring = mystring.PadRight(10).Substring(0, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.Format` with a custom format string:

```
mystring = string.Format("{0,-10}", mystring);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `string.PadRight` method:

```
string result = mystring.PadRight(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  string str = "cc";

        int charstoinsert = 10 - str.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < charstoinsert; i++)
        {
            str += " ";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following function

```
#region GetPaddedString

        private string GetPaddedString(string strValue, int intLength)
        {
            string strReturn = string.Empty;

            string _strEmptySpace = " ";

            int _vinLength = strValue.Length;

            if (_vinLength < intLength)
            {
                strReturn = strValue + _strEmptySpace.PadRight((intLength - _vinLength));
            }
            else
            {
                strReturn = strValue;
            }

            return strReturn;

        }

        #endregion

GetPaddedString("test", 10)
```

Comment: Why not just using the `PadRight` method?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
str.PadRight(10, ' ').Substring(0, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string mystring= "sd";
        while (mystring.Length <= 10)
        {
            mystring+= " ";
        }
```